# Orchard Projection Widget with pager issue

Tags: widget, orchardcms, projection

I'm working on a website made with Orchard CMS. I put a Projection Widget on a page with a custom query and it works perfectly but if there is a pager on that page and I click to another page (not to the first) the Projection Widget becomes empty. So it shows result only on the first page of the pager.

Is this an Orchard bug or am I doing something wrong maybe? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the pager on that widget to use a different pagination parameter.